# How to Start InteractionAfter Stop Interaction With Jupyter and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When using `%matplotlib notebook` in a Jupyter notebook, plots are interactive. Each plot includes a "Stop interaction" button, which turns off interactive mode for that plot.

After one presses "Stop interaction", is there a way to "Start interaction" without re-running the cell that created the plot?

(I don't want to redo the downloads and the calculations -- just toggle the plot back to interactive.)

Comment: Did you find an answer? Just run into this myself.